# JS. Конвертация html в формат для текcтового редактора

Tags: html, ms-word

Есть ли универсальный плагин для данной задачи? 
Использовал https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html
Но не можно файл открыть ни в LibreOffice ни в Google Docs с нормальным результатом. Нужно чтобы подтягивало и стили и картинки. Спасибо

Comment: Markdown конверторы, их целая стая из HTML в MD.

Comment: В чем проблема у Ctrl+A Ctrl+C Alt-Tab Ctrl+V ?

Comment: Ctrl+C Ctrl+V ? Вы точно там пишете?) Это stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть ли универсальный плагин для данной задачи?

Самое близкое к тому, что вы хотите.

Этот пример со встроенным `div`-ом.

```js
function html2doc(element, filename = '') {
  var html = `<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Export HTML To Doc</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   ${document.getElementById(element).innerHTML}
  </body>
 </html>`;

  var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
    type: 'application/msword'
  });

  // Specify link url
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

  // Specify file name
  filename = filename ? filename + '.doc' : 'document.doc';

  // Create download link element
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = url;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="editor">
  <!-- Your content here -->
  <h1> This is a title</h1>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/200X300" alt="https://unsplash.com/" title="placeholder unsplash.com">
  <p>
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo.
  </p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p class="red" style="background: red;">
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo.
  </p>
</div>
<hr>
<button onclick="html2doc('editor', 'word-content');">Export as .doc</button>
```

---

Этот вариант не работает в `jsfiddle`, потому как использует `iframe`, в том же `codepen.io` все отлично работает.

Тут используется `CKEditor 4`, что позволяет сохранять стили *inline* и втавлять фотки, открывается все и в LibreOffice (`Version: 6.0.*.*`) и в MS Word.

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// ckeditor 4 
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
})

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// 
function html2doc(element, filename = '') {
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // 
  var iframe = document.querySelector(element);
  var doc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  var html = `<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Export HTML To Doc</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   ${ doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML }
  </body>
 </html>`;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  console.log(html);
  var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
    type: 'application/msword'
  });

  // Specify link url
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

  // Specify file name
  filename = filename ? filename + '.doc' : 'document.doc';

  // Create download link element
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = url;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="editor"></textarea>
<hr>
<button onclick="html2doc('.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset', 'word-content');">Export as .doc</button>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: Это замечательно! Большое спасибо. Таблицы тоже корректно отображаются)

Comment: В LibreOffice картинки отображаются нормально, но в MS Office картинки не отображаются, как будто картинки не найдены. Можно ли это как-то решить?

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк отображаются, если разрешить изменения `enable editing` документа, так у MS защитная реакция на фотки.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, именно в Word формат плохая идея конвертировать, так как скорее всего будет много проблем с версткой документа.

Но если очень нужно можно [такой вариант](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js). Правда придется тащить весь этот проект, но попробовать можно.

Советую попробовать конвертировать в простой txt формат с помощью [вот этого npm пакета](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text). Мне кажется, это более удобный и простой формат.

Comment: Та да в докс плохая идея, но заказчик хочет докс...ну или текстовый формат который бы открывался в популярных текстовых редакторах. Тот что вы предложили (html-docx-js) и используется уже на сайте, но к сожалению не открывается корректно документ ни в чем кроме MS, и гугл доки не поддерживают. А вот c html-to-text, чтото я застрял на этапе как это добро правильно сохранить как файл

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк тогда можно рассмотреть вариант html -> markdown -> docx, гугл даст необходимые ссылки