# Сохранить (конвертировать) часть страницы HTML в Word (doc/docx) с картинками

Tags: javascript, php

Сайт написан на чистом PHP с JS. На некоторых страницах нужно добавить кнопку "сохранить в Word" по нажатию на которую будет сохраняться блок например с id="source-html" с его содержимым в Word документ (ну и скачиваться на ком). Картинки должны вставляться не ссылками, а быть прямо в документе. Реализация нужна максимально простая, так как не хочется грузить простейший сайт супер системой конвертирования с миллионом плагинов (да и я туповат чтобы такое реализовать).

Тут простейший вариант https://it-blog.ru/js/kak-konvertirovat-html-v-word-na-javascript/ но он не сохраняет картинки =(
Тут вроди работает [JS. Конвертация html в формат для текcтового редактора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841042/js-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-html-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BAc%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) но много кода да и варианту уже 5 лет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, простое современное решение.

Comment: Попробуйте поискать плагины конвертации в формат rtf. Это очень старый формат, про него уже многие забыли, но он открывается почти всеми текстовыми редакторами.

Comment: А что касается современных методов, то можно воспользоваться внешними сервисами. Например https://docs.aspose.cloud/total/getting-started/quickstart/

Comment: @ВикторКарев
В каком смысле внешними сервисами? Я же объяснил что это мой сайт на котором все должно работать автоматически